# Write a function called justify that takes a list of strings and a filed size then returns a single string

Tags: python

Write a function called justify that takes a list of strings and a filed size then returns a single string. The return string will have the original words spaced out in a string of length size. e.g.

```
justify([“this”, “is”, “a”, “test”],20) à “this is a test”
```

We are putting 11 characters in a 20 space field, so we have 9 extra spaces. There are 3 places between the words, so we have 3 spaces between each word. If the extra spaces do not divide exactly you can distribute the extra spaces as you like.

```
'justify([“all”, “too”, “easy”],15) à “all too easy”'
```

If the field size is too small to add one space between the words then ignore the field size and return the answer with one space between each word.

```
def justify(x,y):
    amount = len(x)-1
    final = "".join(x)
    ohmy = len(final)
    spaces = y - ohmy
    real = spaces / amount
    print(real)

    just = []

length = int(input("length: "))

while True:
    hi = input("word: ")
    if hi == "end":
        break
    else:
        just.append(hi)

justify(just,length)
```

This is what I have? Any help?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format the code. See: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: `any help?` - Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to

- calculate the space taken up by all the words/strings;
- find the difference between the limit and the space taken by the words;
- divide that difference by the number of *gaps* between words;
- use that result to decide where and how many spaces to put between the words;
- construct a string with the words and the spaces.
- add logic to check if length of words is greater than field space and react to that